# Beautiful Soup trouble getting nested HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Using Beautiful soup, I can't seem to capture ALL of the HTML elements. Specifically, I aim to try to get the `4` value in

```
    <button class="css-812ha7 " type="button">4</button>
```

but I am having trouble doing so using beautiful soup because I can't capture the nested tags

Code:

```
soup.select('.css-rs2cuv')
```

Returns:

```
[
     <div class="css-rs2cuv">
         <button class="css-rzdbbc" type="button">
             <svg class="css-1jc5boz" viewbox="0 95 57 95">
                 <path d="M57 142.5L9.5"></path>
             </svg>
         </button>
         <button class="css-rzdbbc" type="button">
             <svg class="css-15yx468" viewbox="0 95 57 95">
                 <path d="M57 142.5L9.5 95 0 104.5l38"></path>
             </svg>
         </button>
     </div>
]
```

I thought my line of code would return all the tags and nested tags and then I can just run more methods to grab my desired value

HTML I am parsing:

```
<div class="css-rs2cuv">
    <button class="css-rzdbbc" type="button">
        <svg viewBox="0 95 57 95" class="css-1jc5boz">
             <path d="M57 142.5L9.5"></path>
        </svg>
    </button>
    <button class="css-10po51q " type="button">1</button>
    <button class="css-812ha7 " type="button">2</button>
    <button class="css-812ha7 " type="button">3</button>
    <div class="css-ufx8pa " data-comp="Flex Box">...</div>
    <button class="css-812ha7 " type="button">4</button>
    <button class="css-mnn3vx " type="button">
        <svg viewBox="0 95 57 95" class="css-15yx468 ">
            <path d="M57 142.5L9.5 95 0 104.5l38"></path>
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[select](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) returns a list of all tags matching that tag.You can use an index to this list to get your required tag and then use `.text` to get the text inside.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div class="css-rs2cuv">
    <button class="css-rzdbbc" type="button">
        <svg viewBox="0 95 57 95" class="css-1jc5boz">
             <path d="M57 142.5L9.5"></path>
        </svg>
    </button>
    <button class="css-10po51q " type="button">1</button>
    <button class="css-812ha7 " type="button">2</button>
    <button class="css-812ha7 " type="button">3</button>
    <div class="css-ufx8pa " data-comp="Flex Box">...</div>
    <button class="css-812ha7 " type="button">4</button>
    <button class="css-mnn3vx " type="button">
        <svg viewBox="0 95 57 95" class="css-15yx468 ">
            <path d="M57 142.5L9.5 95 0 104.5l38"></path>
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select('.css-812ha7')[2].text)
```

Output

```
4
```

Comment: I used lxml parser. Would this make a difference?

Comment: @Liondancer No. I just tested it.

Comment: I tried `soup.select('.css-812ha7')` but my code returns []

Comment: @Liondancer I hope you got the output.

Comment: With your example I did but I think my python code it giving me different HTML for some reason compared to my browser

Comment: @Liondancer Sometimes setting a user agent similar to your browser will solve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186566/discussion-between-liondancer-and-bitto-bennichan).

Answer (score 1):

Not enough html to tell if you would need to use `select` or `select_one` (`select_one` will return first match), but for html shown you can use the relationship between the attribute of the element before the desired one (by specifying an [attribute=value selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) of [`data-comp='Flex Box']`) , in adjacent sibling combination with the class of the element you want to grab. The `+` is an [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

With multiple matches for this css selector combination, and where not the first, `select` can be used to retrieve all matches; you can index into that to retrieve a specific item.

In this scenario using class name alone, as a selector, would almost certainly be quicker but worth being aware of other methods.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div class="css-rs2cuv">
    <button class="css-rzdbbc" type="button">
        <svg viewBox="0 95 57 95" class="css-1jc5boz">
             <path d="M57 142.5L9.5"></path>
        </svg>
    </button>
    <button class="css-10po51q " type="button">1</button>
    <button class="css-812ha7 " type="button">2</button>
    <button class="css-812ha7 " type="button">3</button>
    <div class="css-ufx8pa " data-comp="Flex Box">...</div>
    <button class="css-812ha7 " type="button">4</button>
    <button class="css-mnn3vx " type="button">
        <svg viewBox="0 95 57 95" class="css-15yx468 ">
            <path d="M57 142.5L9.5 95 0 104.5l38"></path>
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print(soup.select_one("[data-comp='Flex Box'] + .css-812ha7").text)
```

Comment: Turns out my code was grabbing the page source and my browser had different source because of JS rendering =/